# Java: file write error, access is denied

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create an XML File in my `C:\` directory and every time I launch the program, it says Access Is Denied. The following is my code:

```
public void buildXML(){
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory xmlFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder doc = xmlFac.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document settings = doc.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = settings.createElement("AppSettings");

        rootElement.appendChild(settings.createElement("FAK0"));

        TransformerFactory transform = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer former = transform.newTransformer();
        DOMSource src = new DOMSource(settings);
        StreamResult res = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

        former.transform(src, res);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e+"");
    }
}
```

And here is the output on the console:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\file.xml (Access is denied)
```

Is it because I have no administrator access or what? If it is then that would be very unsettling.

Comment: Yeah it is more likely that its because of permission issues. Try to  create the file in the same location as your java file to confirm the issue.

Comment: Do you absolutely must create the file on `C:`? On any other partition it should work.

Comment: @Fyre it works with my current directory

Comment: @GabrielNegut I actually need it to be in the Windows Directory, so yeah.

Comment: Then this is permission issue. You dont have the access to write the C drive. You could try to open your cmd as administrator and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. Perhaps the file is open and edited by another program
2. Or as the others have suggested about permissions.

Check to see if a file.xml exists in that location.